# Getting the index of a players rank by points

Tags: python, lambda, indexing

I'm trying to get a players numbered rank of how high their points are in my DB file. For example:

```
user points.
rich 15
tom 19
bob 7
```

So tom's rank would #1, because he has the highest, then it would be rich at #2 and lastly bob at #3 and etc.

I thought about using lambda and index but I highly doubt it will work. This is is what it looks likes so far:

```
def rank():
    datalist = sorted(Point.dPoint.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
    rank = datalist.index(l[0], beg=1, len(datalist))
    return rank
```

Comment: `but I highly doubt it will work.` Have you tried? Also what data structure do you use? Is it a dictionary with users as keys and points as values?

Comment: Yes its a dict. users is the first value and points is the second value. And not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"rich": 15, "tom": 19, "bob": 7}
print list(enumerate(sorted(data, key = lambda x: int(data[x]), reverse=True),1))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'tom'), (2, 'rich'), (3, 'bob')]
```

You can extend it further, like this, to get the ranks of the individual people

```
def calculate_rank(data):
    data = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(sorted(data,key=lambda x:int(data[x]),reverse=True),1)}
    def get_rank(name):
        return data[name]
    return get_rank

get_rank = calculate_rank({"rich": 15, "tom": 19, "bob": 7})
print "You are ranked #{}".format(get_rank("tom"))
print "You are ranked #{}".format(get_rank("rich"))
print "You are ranked #{}".format(get_rank("bob"))
```

Comment: Nice. So how would I get the just a name and the rank they are at? Like if I was my name is rich and I did !ccrank it would return "You are ranked #2"

Comment: Aw xD now your messing with me but okay. Thanks for the help